# How to convert float to string in Delphi specifying Significant Digits, not Decimal Digits (and not G format)

Tags: delphi-2007, formatting, significant-digits

I usually print numbers with a specific number of decimal digits, but I now need to print one with a specified number of significant digits.  The numbers need to be like "1.23" not like "1.2 E0".  I see that Delphi will do the latter with the G format, but I cannot see how to do this in the former format.

Comment: How do you _print_ the numbers? show some code!

Answer (score 3):

Use Format:

`Format('%.3g',[Value]));`

The 'g' specifies significant figures, I'll let you work out what the 3 means...

Answer (score 0):

FormatFloat('0.000', YourFloatNumber)

Use as many zeros as you would need to represent the digits.

Comment: 'significant digits' does not specify a fixed number of decimals. Here's a link if you'd like to learn more: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Significant_figures

Answer (score 0):

`Format('%.2g', MyNumber)` => limit the output to 2 decimals
`FormatFloat('0.00', MyNumber)` => force exactly 2 decimals

Example:

```
MyNumber1 := 2
MyNumber2 := 3.8
MyNumber3 := 4.97

WriteLn(Format('Variant 1: %.2g / %.2g / %.2g', [MyNumber1, MyNumber2, MyNumber3]));
WriteLn(Format('Variant 2: %s / %s / %s', [FormatFloat('0.00', MyNumber1), FormatFloat('0.00', MyNumber2), FormatFloat('0.00', MyNumber3)]));
```

Output:

> Variant 1: 2 / 3.8 / 4.97
> Variant 2: 2.00 / 3.80 / 4.97